# Add character after a condition

Tags: r, regex

```
stringg <- c("You are\ngoing to learn 3 things, the first one is not to extract, and\n2 and 3 are simply digits.", "....", "....",....)
```

in R Studio I want to find all listitem/strings which ends with a "." and after the dot I want to add a $ sign to it.

```
grep("\\.$", stringg , value = TRUE) # this gives me the string from list which ends with a dot
```

with which command can I add the $?

I know I could use str_replace like following but I want to know if I could add instead of replacing it?

```
str_replace(stringg, "\\.$", ".$")
```

thanks!

Comment: `paste0(dot_regex, "$")`

Comment: will this add next to my "\\.$" regex condition?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question. `str_replace(stringg, "(\\.)$", "\\1$")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to add a char to a string ending with a specific character.

Here are a few with the major three regex engines used in R regex functions:

```r
stringg <- c("You are\ngoing to learn 3 things, the first one is not to extract, and\n2 and 3 are simply digits.", "....", "....")
sub("(\\.)$", "\\1$", stringg)
sub("$(?<=\\.)", "$", stringg, perl=TRUE)
library(stringr)
str_replace(stringg, "\\.$", "\\0$")
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/avn9QO).

**Details**

- `sub("(\\.)$", "\\1$", stringg)` - **TRE regex**: `(\.)` captures a literal dot into a capturing group with ID 1 and then `$` asserts the position at the end of string, and then the match (the dot) is replaced with the same value that is stored in Group 1 (see the `\1` backreference) and then a `$` is added.
- `sub("$(?<=\\.)", "$", stringg, perl=TRUE)` - **PCRE regex**: matches the end of string with `$` and then checks if there is a dot immediately to the left of the current location with the help of the `(?<=\.)` positive lookbehind and then  the location is replaced with `$`, i.e. the `$` is just appended to the end of string
- `str_replace(stringg, "\\.$", "\\0$")`  - **ICU regex**: here, it is almost the same example as with the TRE regex above, but there is no need capturing the whole consuming pattern (the dot) since the `stringr` functions support the zeroth backreference, the one that refers to the whole match value. So, the `.` at the end of string is matched with the `\.$` pattern and `\0$` replaces the match with itself, with `.`, and `$` is appended.